# How to access Facts created inside a DRL from a KieSession?

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, kie

I create a DRL file as below -

```
rule 'CHECK_AGE_LIMIT'
       when        
              $payroll : Payroll();
              Participant(null != dob, $dob : dob);
              Plan(null!= eligibilityAge, $eligibilityAge:eligibilityAge);
              eval (!(Period.between($dob, LocalDate.now()).getYears() > $eligibilityAge))
       then
            Result $result = new Result(false, "Age Eligibility Not Met");
            insert( $result ); 
       end
```

How can I access the result from the calling Java class.

This is how I call the DRL -

```
    commands.add(CommandFactory.newFireAllRules());
    commands.add(CommandFactory.newGetObjects(GET_OBJECTS_KEY));
    ExecutionResults executionResults = kSession.execute(CommandFactory.newBatchExecution(commands));
```

While I can access all the Facts that I passed on to the DRL, I cant seem to find a way to access, how to Access result.

I know that I can just pass Result as a fact to the DRL. Just want to understand if there's a way to access something that is created inside the DRL.

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to access `$result`, which you added to the working memory?

Comment: What exactly you are passing as `GET_OBJECTS_KEY` ?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas well no.. while I know that I can access $result can be accessed... I wanted to check if I can create a new `Result` and access it from the calling Java class

Comment: @AntonGiertli  GET_OBJECTS_KEY = "_getObjects"

Answer (score 1):

I believe the getObjectsCommands is a way to go. Please make sure you are passing proper filter - it seems you are passing String into getObjectsCommand constructor, which is specifying "output-identifier" and not the filter.
Here is an example, which should be compatible with your use case:

```
ObjectFilter filter = new ObjectFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof Result) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
commands.add(CommandFactory.newGetObjects(filter));
```